# Observing the wavefunction as a whole

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

I there a way to observe/graph the wave function of an electron, for example, if you had an electron, you would get the wave function somehow by observing it, and it would produce something like this:
[image]

Comment: The wave function isn't observable. Where's your question, please?

Comment: And the mathematical shape of the wave function depends enormously on the shape of the potential function $U(r)$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to this is a bit nuanced so I have now edited the answer to make it as clear as possible.

The big picture is: Yes, it is possible to measure a wave function, if it is possible to find or produce particles with that wave function so that repeated measurements can be made (not on the same particle each time, but on a different particle which is known to have the same wave function). This can be done in practice. For example, this experiment effectively measures the magnitude of the wave function in momentum space for an electron in a hydrogen atom: [source.](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.13312)

If you write 
$$\psi(\vec{r})=A(\vec{r})e^{i\alpha(\vec{r})}$$
For $A,\alpha$ real, then $A$ can be determined by measurements of position, and I believe it is possible to find $\alpha$ only from momentum measurements up to a constant offset $\alpha(x) \to \alpha(x) + c$. Because of this constant offset which is not measurable, $\psi(\vec{r})$ is not measurable at a point, but $|\psi(\vec{r})|^2 $ is, $A(\vec{r})$ is, and $\alpha(\vec{r})$ is up to that "offset", which is called a global phase.

Of course, any finite number of measurements will only give information on a finite number of points of $\psi(\vec{r})$, each with uncertainty as well, especially because many measurements are necessary to measure a probability. These measurements must be done by repeatedly preparing a particle in that wave function and then measuring at a chosen later time. The experimentalist does not need to know *what* the wave function is beforehand, she/he must only know that the wave function is the same for each particle. Then, she can interpolate in between the measured points to come to a good guess for $\psi$ at all points. In practice, *any* experimental outcome which is predicted by $\psi(\vec{r})$ can also be used to constrain it.

There is a practice of measuring states called Quantum Tomography. It has its own wikipedia. It is usually used for finite-dimensional systems. But in reality every system is infinite dimensional, one only treats them as finite-dimensional. One could treat the position space wave function in the same way.

That being said, though it can be done in principle, I'm not aware of a full tomography which has been done in practice. If one really doesn't exist, this is a severe experimental weakness of testing the theory in my view. If anyone has a source to one, I'd be interested. I know of many momentum experiments where the fourier transform of the wave function was in fact checked, but not the entire thing.

I will point out again for clarity, because it seems that others are of the opinion that I have not emphasized this enough, that *if* you do not have the ability to find or produce many particles in the unknown state $\psi$ then it is not possible to measure in practice. It seems to me, though, that a clever setup could be used to measure almost any wave function in principle. Whether technology has reached that point is another question. But I will do due dilligence and flag that last statement as opinion, because I cannot provide references or proofs that it *must* be so.

Comment: The key point being that the wavefunction of a particular electron can't be measured, but if a large number of electrons can be prepared in identical states so they have identical wavefunctions, then the wavefunction can be measured statistically.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point. It takes a statistical number of measurements to determine the wave function, but each measurement changes it, so it's necessary to repeat the experiment many times.

Comment: One only can measure he probability =$ Ψ^*Ψ$ , the complex conjugate squared ,  and this is a real number, whereas $Ψ$ is a complex number function. So we only get a "projection:" of the possible mathematica form of the wavefunction, the phases are lost .

Comment: @annav that is not true, the phase carries information about the fourier transform of the wave function.Just write $\psi$ in complex polar coordinates as in my answer and take the fourier transform, the quantity $|\hat{\psi}(p)|^2$ depends on $\alpha$, so the phase can be measured too. I have read that this is sufficient to fully determine the phase but I don't know any details so I didn't want to make that claim strongly. Instead of measuring the momentum it is also possible to measure the position at a later time to infer what the phase *was* previously.Also whoever downvoted please explain

Comment: You give a specific function. Generally solutions of the quantum differential equations do not have such a simple form due to the form of the potentials. see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.08172.pdf

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to say, what do you mean by "you give a specific function"? I know that $\psi(\vec{r})$ is in practice not simple to express in terms of elementary functions, but when I say that it can be measured that is not what I mean. I only mean that one can experimentally determine $A(\vec{r})$ and $\alpha(\vec{r})$ in a numerical way, with uncertainty, for a finite certain range of values in the domain. If that range contains a large percent of the wave function area the tomography is a good representation of the actual wave function.

Comment: _There is a practice of measuring states called Quantum Tomography_ Quantum Tomography is only used for reconstructing a density matrix, which elements are defined as $$ \rho_{mn}(t) = a_m(t)\,a^*_n(t). $$ So density matrix elements are **each state probability densities**. So Quantum Tomography measures all outcome probabilities in state space. So, it has nothing to do with quantum state measurement or wavefunction measurement. And wiki should be corrected in QT page, it gives false premises.

Comment: Any time a wave function description is appropriate, so for any pure state, knowledge of the density matrix is sufficient to know the wave function (up to the phase $e^{ic}$ of course). So calculating them are one and the same. The diagonal density matrix elements are directly the values $|\psi(\vec{r})|^2$ if $\rho$ is in the position basis. If a wave function description is not appropriate for the system, OP's question doesn't make sense to even ask anyway.

Comment: If I am making a stupid mistake here, I would be glad to know it and would delete my answer. I'm happy to take any discussion to chat to discuss in case that is the case. But as it stands, I don't see the issues. Maybe it is due to the limitations of conversation in a text-only format like this that the full conversation is difficult to have.

Comment: _knowledge of the density matrix is sufficient to know the wave function_ No, it's not. Probability densities are wavefunction squared, so it's **not** plain wavefunction itself. There are no ways to measure $\psi(\vec{r})$ directly and that was question about it. So your answer is basically FALSE.

Comment: Please be more careful, what you said is not true. The only element of $\psi$ which has no effect on experiment is the global phase $e^{i c}$. The rest has an impact on probabilities *in some basis*. So while it is true that position measurements only give back $|\psi(\vec{r})|^2$, measurements in other bases determine the local phase $e^{i \alpha (x)}$. Since all of these probabilities can equivalently be written in terms of density matrices, one can reproduce the entire wave function $\psi$ from a density matrix except for the global phase.

Comment: _one can reproduce the entire wave function  from a density matrix **except** for the global phase_ No, it's you who needs to be more careful. Your saying is like "I can bake a cake, but only to a half-baked degree". You either can bake a cake or not, semi-results does not counts. Same here, if you can't restore **full original** $\psi$ with all phase info which you started from,- then this means that you can't know wavefunction from measuring probabilities.

Comment: Okay, so we agree, that besides the global phase the wave function can be reconstructed from the density matrix. That is what I always wrote. If you interpret that as half-baked that is subjective and I can't do anything about it.

Comment: If you omit phase info, then you omit wavefunction itself. So no - I don't agree with your view. You simply overestimate density matrix abilities. Btw, can you show formula of backwards mapping from density matrix into wavefunction ? Never heard about it, would be nice to see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105978/discussion-between-doublefelix-and-agnius-vasiliauskas).

Answer (score 4):

We cannot observe an individual wave function. We can, by taking many measurements of a repeated experiment, observe a probability distribution which can be calculated from the wave function. However, this does not constitute the measurement of a wave function because wave functions are complex-valued and because phase is indeterminate. One particular counter example is the wave function of a spin-half particle, such as an electron. If you turn around, the wave function will be inverted. There is no chance of observing anything which behaves like that.